# How can I fix - Fatal error: Cannot declare class WP_User_Request?

Tags: wordpress, error-handling, fatal-error, wordpress-ecommerce

Error:

> Fatal error: Cannot declare class WP_User_Request, because the name is already in use in /home/zo8v2bw96l60/public_html/wp-includes/user.php on line 3657

Here's what I found on line 3657:

```
/**
 * WP_User_Request class.
 *
 * Represents user request data loaded from a WP_Post object.
 *
 * @since 4.9.6
 */
final class WP_User_Request {
    /**
     * Request ID.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $ID = 0;
```

How did this happen?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my case by reinstalling wordpress, redownloaded and replaced the files